# sendToURL not working in flashplayer 14

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

This piece of code is working in flashplayer 11 but it's not working in flashplayer 14.

**AS3 code :**

```
private function savePDF(pdfBinary:ByteArray, urlString:String):void{

try{

    //result comes back as binary, create a new URL request and pass it back to the server
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

    var sendRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
        sendRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
        sendRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        sendRequest.data = pdfBinary;                
        sendToURL(sendRequest);

    } catch (e:Error) {
        // handle error here
        trace("Error in savePDF "+e.message);
        trace("StackTrace : "+e.getStackTrace());
    }

}
```

and these are the errors I got :

```
Error in savePDF Error #3769: Security sandbox violation: Only simple headers can be used with navigateToUrl() or sendToUrl().
StackTrace : SecurityError: Error #3769: Security sandbox violation: Only simple headers can be used with navigateToUrl() or sendToUrl().
    at global/flash.net::sendToURL()
    at Export2Publish/savePDF()[my_project_dir\src\Export2Publish.mxml:158]
    at Export2Publish/GeneratePDF()[my_project_dir\src\Export2Publish.mxml:386]
    at Export2Publish/getUrl()[my_project_dir\src\Export2Publish.mxml:138]
    at Export2Publish/___Export2Publish_Application1_creationComplete()[my_project_dir\src\Export2Publish.mxml:3]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[my_framework_dir\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9051]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[my_framework_dir\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1167]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[my_framework_dir\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:698]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher2()[my_framework_dir\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8460]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()[my_framework_dir\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8403]
```

Any fix for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using a `try` and `catch` like this :

```
try {
    sendToURL(request);
}
catch (e:Error) {
    // handle error here
}
```

If the problem is not visible on dev environment, I recommand you to install a flash debug player which you can download here : [Flash Player Downloads](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) to see what kind of error your code will fire.

If your code is fine, in dev and prod environment, you should debug your server side script.

Comment: I got the following error SecurityError: Error #3769: Security sandbox violation: Only simple headers can be used with navigateToUrl() or sendToUrl(). Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: I think this is a bug in flash player 13.0 an up. Take a look here : https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3759971, but you can try using ` URLLoader ` instead of ` sendToURL `.

Comment: can you please convert the above code such that it uses  URLLoader  instead of  sendToURL

Comment: I can't "convert" and test your code like this but you can try this : ( this is an untested code, I wrote it just to give you idea and I am not sure that URLLoader will solve your problem or not because I didnt test it ) : `var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(your_url); request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; request.contentType = 'multipart/form-data'; request.data = your_byte_array; var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY; loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_on_Complete); loader.load(request); `

Comment: I get the following error :: * Security Sandbox Violation *
Connection to https:my_url_string halted - not permitted from file:///D:/SCOR/FLex/Export2Publish_new/bin-debug/Export2Publish.swf
Error in savePDF Error #2176: Certain actions, such as those that display a pop-up window, may only be invoked upon user interaction, for example by a mouse click or button press.
StackTrace : SecurityError: Error #2176: Certain actions, such as those that display a pop-up window, may only be invoked upon user interaction, for example by a mouse click or button press.
 at flash.net::URLStream/load()

Comment: You've got this error in dev or prod mode ? and reassure me that my_url_string contains a real url !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64030/discussion-between-akmozo-and-krsna-chaitanya).

Comment: I cannt open the chat url since it is blocked in our VPN. I got the error in dev mode. my_url_string contains a real url.